# what's the difference between requests.post and this straight curl?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, battlenet-api

Using python 3.6.2 with `requests` library.

I'm trying to authenticate with oauth2 on battle.net APIs, and on the second request (the one for token retrieval) I'm getting a 400 error with no useful explanation ("internal server error"). 
Someone on the battle.net forum suggested to try to do the same `POST` with a `curl`, and it works. (here's my forum post: https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20762236765)

I checked many times for some stupid difference between the two (maybe a typo), but there aren't (I also written back the request from the curl by copypasting, obtaining the same error). So I suppose there should be some actual difference in behaviour between the two.

Here's the python code:

```
data = {
         'code': code,
         'redirect_uri': 'https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback',
         'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
         'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
         'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
         'scope': 'sc2.profile'
    }
resp = requests.post('https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token', data=data)
```

And here's the curl:

```
curl -X POST -s "https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token" \
    -d client_id='<same as above>' \
    -d client_secret='<same as above>'  \
    -d grant_type='authorization_code' \
    -d redirect_uri='https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback' \
    -d scope='sc2.profile'  \
    -d code='<same as above>'
```

As I said, I guess there should be something different, but I'm no expert of http. Something in the headers maybe? How can I set requests to have the same behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to manually encode the `redirect_uri`; `requests` will do that for you.

```
data = {
     'code': code,
     'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost/oauth2callback',
     'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
     'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
     'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
     'scope': 'sc2.profile'
}
resp = requests.post('https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token', data=data)
```

The equivalent `curl` call would use `--data-urlencode` instead of `-d`/`--data`.

```
curl -X POST -s "https://eu.battle.net/oauth/token" \
    -d client_id='<same as above>' \
    -d client_secret='<same as above>'  \
    -d grant_type='authorization_code' \
    --data-urlencode redirect_uri='https://localhost/Foauth2callback' \
    -d scope='sc2.profile'  \
    -d code='<same as above>'
```

To debug problems like this, you can post to `https://httpbin.org/post`; the response will show you exactly what data was sent in the POST request.

Comment: I already tried to not encode that uri, but I got the same error. Tonight I'll try httpbin.org and let you now what i find

Comment: There could be an issue with the three values you don’t show as well.

Comment: ok sorry, probably last night I was tired, and I made some mistake in the encoding/decoding stuff. Actually _that_ was the problem, thanks.